# How to remove duplicate query on page load or make them cacheable

Tags: query, cache

I'm having the same issue as [Lletnek](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/duplicate-query-showing-in-db-query?replies=5) where there are the same duplicate queries for `get_page_by_path` on some of the pages on our website. I have got the queries down to 2/3 on most pages using Memcached Redux and `WP_Object` cache. The goal is 0 queries. It seems strange that WP doesn't cache the `get_page_by_path` or the `get_posts` or `get_pages`. If it does it's a very short expiration.

The query in question is

```
SELECT ID, post_name, post_parent, post_type
FROM poststable
WHERE post_name IN ('slug')
AND post_type IN ('page','attachment')
```

The callers are

```
get_page_by_path()
 wp-includes/post.php:4255-
WP_Query->parse_query()
 wp-includes/query.php:1799
WP_Query->get_posts()
 wp-includes/query.php:2480
WP_Query->query()
 wp-includes/query.php:4006
WP->query_posts()
 wp-includes/class-wp.php:608
WP->main()
 wp-includes/class-wp.php:726
wp()
 wp-includes/functions.php:952
```

and

```
WP_Query->get_posts()
 wp-includes/query.php:3613-
WP_Query->query()
 wp-includes/query.php:4006
WP->query_posts()
 wp-includes/class-wp.php:608
WP->main()
 wp-includes/class-wp.php:726
wp()
 wp-includes/functions.php:952
```

I looked into `use_verbose_page_rules` that John mentioned in the [linked](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/duplicate-query-showing-in-db-query?replies=5) post but I couldn't find out much about it. We are using permalinks like `/sample-post/`.

I have also tried setting a base for the category permalinks but it hasn't changed anything. We don't even have any posts or categories just pages.

So my question is How can I remove the second `get_page_by_path` query and/or then cache the results?